# Bonferroni Multiple comparisons -- testing for any true

Tags: multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I am doing multiple comparisons with several thousand independent alternatives. None are statistically significant when Bonferroni corrected; however, many more are significant when uncorrected than expected by chance, so I compute this probability to show that most of my low p-valued tests are true.

Can anyone point me to a citable paper (for a referee) on this approach. I found it discussed (with citation missing!) in wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons#Assessing_whether_any_alternative_hypotheses_are_true

thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should try a method based on false discovery rate control? It does exactly what you attempt to do (control the proportion of false positives among all your positives), but in a "safe" way. For example, use the Benjamini & Hochberg method is quite popular (you can use `p.adjust()` with `method="fdr"`in R).

Comment: thanks, that's a good direction for my next step, but for now I just want a reference for the simpler idea that even though the bonferronis are all non-significant, many truly are significant. This is clearly implicit in the Benjamin and Hochberg paper, but presumably there's an earlier paper that discusses this explicitly and is the more relevant citation.

Comment: Have you looked into Fisher's method and variants e.g. [Zaykin et al. 2002](ftp://statgen.ncsu.edu/pub/zaykin/tpm/tpmfinal.pdf)?